# How to assign an array of objects within a smarty template file

Tags: php, smarty

I have an array of stdclass objects.
How can I assign it to a smarty template?

I tried to do this:

```
$smarty->assign( 'objects', $x->getAllObjects() );
```

but the result is an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Object could not be converted to string
```

Thanks

**edit**: I also tried:

```
$smarty->registerObject( 'objects', $x->getAllObjects() );
```

and in the template file I did:

```
{foreach from=$objects item=o}
  {$o}
{/foreach}
```

but I get a notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: objects
```

and I can't access the elements of `objects` array.

Comment: please check this url : http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.objects.tpl

Comment: @hardiksolanki I have already checked that link but I still can't find a way to assign the array of objects and access its elements from a template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what is your `$x` and `getAllObjects()` method.

However the following code for assigning objects for Smarty  works without a problem

PHP file:

```
class X
{

    private $_objects;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $a = new StdClass();
        $a->name = 'John';

        $b = new stdClass();
        $b->name = 'Tom';

        $this->_objects[] = $a;
        $this->_objects[] = $b;
    }

    public function getAllObjects()
    {
        return $this->_objects;
    }


}

$x = new X();

$smarty->assign('objects', $x->getAllObjects());
```

Smarty file:

```
{foreach from=$objects item=o}
    {$o->name}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your smarty version.

But looking at the error messager you may need to do the following

```
$smarty->register_object('objects', $x->getAllObjects());
```

Answer (score 0):

`$x->getAllObjects()` is probably returning an object.

you can cast it to a string:

$string = `(string) $x->getAllObjects();`

Comment: I tried this solution but whene I do `{$objects}` in the template file it prints `Array`

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: No because I'm sure the array contains many objects and I want to access to their properties.